# I want to login through instagram in our website

Tags: laravel, symfony

I am using laravel 5.5  i am using laravel package for instagram login 
https://packagist.org/packages/mbarwick83/instagram
When i install laravel passport then the composer error for instagram package 
**Conculusion:remove symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge v0.2**
Can any one tell me how to solve this problem??

Comment: Maybe more packages require `symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge v0.2` but in different versions try `composer why symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge` to find which packages required which versions

Comment: when i am install laravel passporpt symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge is 1.0 and instagram package symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge 0.2 how to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the package itself [see here](https://github.com/mbarwick83/instagram/issues/5).

`laravel/passport` requires `"symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "~1.0"` but the package you are trying to use requires `symfony/psr/-http-msg-bridge v0.2`. So there is a conflict.

You can try and fork the package and check if it works with `"symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "~1.0"` or try to contact the developer.

Comment: Another package for instagram  login in laravel  can you tell me ?/